# How to get $B^{-1}$ from simplex table?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

In each iteration of the simplex method the table has the form:

[image]

I'm reading "Introduction to linear optimization" by Bertsimas and given the following example of a linear program:

[image]

An optimal table for this problem is the following:

[image]

Now he claims that the first column of $B^{-1}$ is (-3,5). I don't see how you can infer that from the table.

Can someonle please tell me how one can read $B^{-1}$ from an optimal table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower right matrix is $B^{-1}A$.

The matrix $A$ is of the form of $[A_1, I]$.

$$B^{-1}[A_1 , I]= [B^{-1}A_1, B^{-1}]$$

That's how he can read it off the table.